# Cannot get log4net to write a log for a browser helper object (BHO) dll

Tags: c#

I'm at my wits end, is it even possible to use log4net with an internet explorer browser helper object (BHO). I've tried just about everything I can find on the web and still no logfile.
My configuration is a separate log4net.config file and a bho that is designed to secure the browser for test takers. The log4net.config file is being picked up by the app and seems to be working, even to the point of an 'IsDebugEnabled' query. It seems to execute the write but nothing results.

**My log4net.config**

```
enter code here
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
</configSections>

<log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <file value="c:\Logs\lockdown.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <!--<filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
    <levelMax value="FATAL" />
  </filter>-->
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %d %-22.22c{1} %-25.25M - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
</root>
</log4net>
</configuration>

public BHO()
    {
        LoadLogging();
        _log  = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        if (_log.IsDebugEnabled)
            _log.Debug("************** Browser session started *************");
    }


    public void LoadLogging()
    {
        Debugger.Launch();
        if (!log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().Configured)
        {
            var codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
            var uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            var pathDataString = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
            var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathDataString);
            var configFile = new FileInfo(path + "\\log4net.config");

            if (!configFile.Exists)
            {
                throw new FileLoadException($"The configuration file {configFile} does not exist.");
            }

            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(configFile);
            
        }
    }


Any help would be appreciated ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it may be possible (but unlikely) that BHOs are blocked from writing to a file, I doubt it would be blocked from writing to the debug window.

Try configuring log4net to write to the debug window:

```
<log4net>  
  <root>  
    <level value="ALL" />  
    <appender-ref ref="DebugAppender"/>  
  </root>  
  <appender name="DebugAppender" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">  
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">  
      <conversionPattern value="%date{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.ffff} [%thread] %level %logger%exception - %message%newline" />  
    </layout>  
  </appender>  
</log4net>
```

Comment: Writing to the debug window worked - Any idea what could be blocking the FileAppender in Windows 10. It works on Win 7